# ItemTemplate for list of items in Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.forms, data-binding

I have a `ListView` with an `ItemTemplate`. For each item in my `ItemSource`, I would like to iterate over a property in the item and create a section in my `ViewCell`.

So every item is a `Download`:

```
public class Download
{
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<SectionDownload> SectionDownloads { get; set; }
}
```

`SectionDownload` looks like this:

```
public class SectionDownload
{
    public long TotalBytes { get; set; }

    public long DownloadedBytes { get; set; }

    public int PercentDownloaded { get => (int)((DownloadedBytes / TotalBytes) * 100); }
}
```

And my `ListView`, where `Downloads` is an `ObservableCollection<Download>` in my ViewModel:

```
<ListView x:Name="DownloadsListView" SelectionMode="None" ItemsSource="{Binding Downloads}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackLayout Padding="10">
                <Label Text="{Binding Title}"
                            d:Text="{Binding .}"
                            LineBreakMode="NoWrap"
                            Style="{DynamicResource ListItemTextStyle}"
                            FontSize="16" />
                <!-- Here I would like each SectionDownload to display the percentage downloaded -->
            </StackLayout>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can display section like this.

```
<ListView x:Name="DownloadsListView" SelectionMode="None" ItemsSource="{Binding Downloads}">
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <StackLayout Padding="10">
            <Label Text="{Binding Title}"
                        d:Text="{Binding .}"
                        LineBreakMode="NoWrap"
                        Style="{DynamicResource ListItemTextStyle}"
                        FontSize="16" />
            <StackLayout BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding SectionDownloads}">
                <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ProgressBar Progress="{Binding PercentDownloaded}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
            </StackLayout>
        </StackLayout>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

The value of PercentDownloaded should be double in range of 0 to 1 and also you have to implement the INotifyPropertyChange to your SectionDownload class for updating the progress in realtime.

Comment: To make it easy to test out I wrapped the ListView in a `RefreshView` with a Command that loads the downloads. And I changed the ProgressBar to a Label.

When I try to add a Download to my ObservableCollection<Download>, I get the error `System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.`

Comment: As this answer provided most of the answer, I'll mark it as the accepted answer. My provided code had an error in it, which made it not work. So like @cole-xia-msft correctly pointed out, the StackLayout needs to be wrapped in a ViewCell.

Answer (score 1):

The error is caused that you did not wrap `Cell` inside `DataTemplate`.

Modify it as

```
<ListView x:Name="DownloadsListView" SelectionMode="None" ItemsSource="{Binding Downloads}">
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <ViewCell>      //add this line
        <StackLayout Padding="10">
            <Label Text="{Binding Title}"
                        d:Text="{Binding .}"
                        LineBreakMode="NoWrap"
                        Style="{DynamicResource ListItemTextStyle}"
                        FontSize="16" />
            <StackLayout BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding SectionDownloads}">
                <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ProgressBar Progress="{Binding PercentDownloaded}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
            </StackLayout>
        </StackLayout>
      </ViewCell>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```